# React onClick function doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built this toy problem to replicate an issue I am facing in a larger app. Why does `handleClick` not fire when the button is clicked?

```
const Button = () => <button type="button">Click me</button>;

export const App = () => {

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("clicked");
  };

  return <Button onClick={handleClick} />;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass `onClick={handleClick}` as a property to `Button` but the `Button` component does not use the property.

```js
const Button = () ... // ⚠️ no onClick property used
```

You can fix this by responding to the `onClick` property -

```js
const Button = ({ onClick }) =>  // ✅
  <button type="button" onClick={onClick}> // ✅
    Click me
  </button>
```

An obvious improvement would be to respond to the `children` property as well. This allows the caller of `Button` to write anything in place of the static `Click me` -

```js
const Button = ({ onClick, children }) =>
  <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>
```

```js
<Button onClick={handleRegister}>Register</Button>
<Button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</Button>
<Button onClick={handleSave}>Save</Button>
```

Note `children` can be passed as a property. Sometimes you will see components use `children` in this way. Both examples function identically -

```js
const Button = ({ onClick, children }) =>
  <button
    type="button"
    onClick={onClick}
    children={children}
  />
```

Another common thing for `Button` components like this is to automatically prevent the default event for the `onClick` handler. We can also accept a `type` property and set the default to `"button"` if the caller does not otherwise specify -

```js
const Button = ({ type = "button", onClick, children, preventDefault = true }) =>
  <button
    type={type}
    onClick={e => {
      if (preventDefault) e.preventDefault()
      onClick(e)
    }}
    children={children}
  />
```

```js
<Button type="submit" onClick={handleRegister}>Register</Button>
<Button onClick={handleReset} preventDefault={false} children="Reset" />
```